# Explained variance modelling a diff (Δ)

Tags: regression, time-series, data-transformation, r-squared

I have a question that I'm struggling with, and it's related with the explained variance of model that uses a "diff" as independent variable ($Δy$=$y_t$-$y_{t-1}$) with the following form:

$Δy$= $x_1*x_2$ + $x_3*x_4$

The results look fine, in terms of the interaction terms and how $Δy$ relates to the covariates, which is one of my interests. My question is regarding the explained variance, which in this case is a bit low (0.24). When modelling $y_t$ and adding the lagged $y_{t-1}$ to the right side as:

$y_t$ = $y_{t-1}$ + $x_1*x_2$ + $x_3*x_4$

the explained variance is much higher (0.9). The models are very similar in terms of interaction surfaces, which is nice and expected.

I am struggling to explain why the "low" explained variance when using $Δy$ in a proper way. I know that even when the explained variance is low, the models are meaningful (which in my case it seems it is). But, how can I explain the reduced explained variance when modelling $Δy$ ?

Just a comment: I am using a gam model, as the relationships are not linear here.

Thanks